# User input that ONLY gets emailed (no db query) -- what are the security issues?

Tags: php, security, email, user-input

I have a form that takes user input of basics such as name, email, location, and then sends an email with these values formatted into a table, for internal use. I was wondering what the security issues involved here are, and how to account for them as close to 100% as possible? I'm using PHP and its mail() function.

So far, all I have is strip_tags applied to all the inputted data. Other than that, there is nearly no validation other than char length count, but even those are fairly large (ex. 80 for name and 255 for email; name having no other validation so as to not cause trouble for foreign names, and email using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL).

Note -- there is no db query (and if there was, I would use a prepared statement as the safeguard for queries), BUT it will be connected to one, if this affects anything.

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Use captcha to avoid spamming. Other than that you should be fine.

Comment: I'd suggest using PHPMailer or SwiftMailer for sending emails from within your PHP script -- those are two good alternatives to `mail()` function.

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm starting to wonder if PHP.net will include the `mail()` function altogether in the next release, the way that people are constantly telling other people to stop using it. The operative words here should be "to start using it properly" ;-)

Comment: @AmalMurali LOL! **Now** would definitely be a good time to start! ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I'll look into PHPMailer, although I am curious as to why mail() is so inferior :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Ahhh yes, very good choice of words ;-) Cheers

Comment: @HC_ The thing about people discouraging others from using the `mail()` function is that many come here to ask for help on the same subject where something goes wrong, and it's with the use of pre-built applications such as PHPMailer and SwiftMailer that make life a lot easier for newbies just starting to adventure themselves in both PHP and forms. You can read up on the subject/function on the [**PHP.net website**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a Captcha to be able to avoid people using it to spam.

Take a look to [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/). its a free CAPTCHA service that helps digitize books, newspapers and old time radio shows. They have useful information in their Webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of right now is to add captcha or something to be secured from spammers.

Comment: Since your rep points are not yet at 50 to comment, which is worthy of by the way, should include some documentation/example(s) to support it.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that the combination of PHP functions that you are using, and the SMTP server combination is not vulnerable to [SMTP Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_IMAP/SMTP_Injection_%28OWASP-DV-011%29).

Otherwise it may be possible to hijack your mail server to send emails or spam to any address.  A CAPTCHA would mitigate this somewhat, but even so you do not want the mail server being vulnerable even if the CAPTCHA response is correct.